# Not getting the right Date offset

Tags: javascript

When I type this:

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

I get the following output: `2020-07-23T09:48:50.348Z`

While my current time is: `2020-07-23T11:48:50.348Z`

My timezone should be GMT+2 but for some reason it is not detecting it. How could this be happening? Do I need to set it manually?

Comment: That output is correct; it's UTC time.

Comment: Use this ```(new Date()).toLocaleString()``` if you don't care about UTC format

Comment: Ahaa so ISO just shows UTC time. 'toLocaleString()' did the trick! Thanks that explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A very long, but methodical, way to get ISOS-like string with timezone offset of date:
Should return 2020-07-23T11:48:50.348+02:00 for you.

```
function toISOSLikeStringWithTimezoneOffset(date) {
  var returnValue="";
  returnValue+=date.getFullYear();
  returnValue+="-";
  returnValue+=("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  returnValue+="-";
  returnValue+=("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  returnValue+="T";
  returnValue+=("0"+date.getHours()).slice(-2);
  returnValue+=":";
  returnValue+=("0"+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  returnValue+=":";
  returnValue+=("0"+date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  returnValue+=".";
  returnValue+=("00"+date.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
  var timezoneOffset=date.getTimezoneOffset();
  returnValue+=timezoneOffset>0?"-":"+";
  timezoneOffset=Math.abs(timezoneOffset);
  var TZOHours=Math.floor(timezoneOffset/60);
  returnValue+=("0"+TZOHours).slice(-2);
  returnValue+=":";
  var TZOMinutes=timezoneOffset%60;
  returnValue+=("0"+TZOMinutes).slice(-2);
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: So?  Good?  Works for you?